# How to calculate 3D histogram in python using open CV

Tags: python, opencv, histogram

I want to calculate 3D histogram of my Cielab image in python. I am using openCV to calculate my histogram. I want to compare images using `compareHist` function of openCV, thats why I am using openCV to compute 3D histogram of my image.

I tried with the following variables:

```
i_lab = image.copy()
i_lab = i_lab.astype(np.uint8)
Range_hist = [[0, 100], [-100, 100], [-100, 100]]    
hist_1 = cv2.calcHist([i_lab], [[0], [1], [2]], None, [[20], [20], [20]], Range_hist)
```

But it gives error `SystemError: error return without exception set`
Please tell me what am I doing wrong and if it is possible to compute 3D histogram using openCV in python

Comment: I used the `compareHist` function on the histogram generated by using numpy library, so I don't need the above function to calculate my histogram anymore.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I came across this question while trying to make a 3D histogram of an HSV image, and encountered the same error. It turns out that the [OpenCV documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/histograms.html#cv2.calcHist) is leading us astray here. The docs are written for the C++ API and as such can only be used as a vague guide to the Python `cv2` API (although I have found that the docs are misleading for C++ as well at times).

The function signature is as follows:

```
cv2.calcHist(images, channels, mask, histSize, ranges[, hist[, accumulate]]) -> hist
```

The key point is that the `channels`, `histSize` and `ranges` parameters should be flat lists, not nested lists as in your example. Try the following, assuming `i_lab` is a three-channel image:

```
range_hist = [0, 100, -100, 100, -100, 100]
hist_1 = cv2.calcHist([i_lab], [0, 1, 2], None, [20, 20, 20], range_hist)
```

For a more complete example, try [this code listing](https://github.com/abidrahmank/OpenCV2-Python/blob/master/Official_Tutorial_Python_Codes/3_imgproc/comparehist.py) from the [opencvpython blog](http://opencvpython.blogspot.com).

Answer (score 0):

For computing a histogram in cielab, this worked for me:

function signature of calcHist: images, channels, mask, number of bins, array of the dims arrays of the histogram bin boundaries in each dimension.

```
img = cv2.imread(file) # in bgr 
hist = cv2.calcHist([img],[0, 1, 2],None,[256, 256, 256],[0, 255, 0, 255, 0, 255]) # in bgr
img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2LAB) # in lab 
hist = cv2.calcHist([img],[0, 1, 2],None,[100, 2*128, 2*128],[0, 100, -128, 127, -128, 127])`# in lab 

correlation = cv2.HISTCMP_CORREL # compare histograms using correlation
corr = cv2.compareHist(img, img2, correlation)
```