# Detecting color range from "average" in OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv, computer-vision, skin

Currently I am using a HaarCascade to detect a face in a picture. Which is working, I am getting a rect of where the face is.

Now I want to get the "average?" (skin color) in that rect. And use that as a base for the color range to search for other skin in the photo. How should I go about that?

I have found the inRange function, which searches for a color in a range. But I am not quite sure how I could get the average color of my skin in there. It seems that the inRange function needs HSV values? However, I don't know quite what that format is. It doesn't seem to be the same as HSB in photoshop. (Which I tried for "testing purposes").

My question boils down to this, how can I get the "average" color in a rect, and find other colours in that range (e.g, lighter and darker than that color, but the same shade).

Thanks.

Comment: [HSL and HSV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV). HSV and HSB are synonymous.

Comment: Quite tricky. Keep in mind that there might be shadows from facial features, which affect the exact color. The benefit of HSV/HSL models is that shadows don't really affect H, whereas they do affect all of R,G and B.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get the 3D color histogram within the detected region of interest. That is, not three 1D histograms for each channel, but one 3D histogram for all 3 channels together. OpenCV's [calcHist](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/histograms.html?highlight=calchist#calchist) has options for that. Here's [an example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15834602/how-to-calculate-3d-histogram-in-python-using-open-cv) which does that. This example is using Python bindings for OpenCV, but it shows how to set the parameters.

Also, set the range of the histogram within a reasonable range for skin color. As MSalters suggested in the comments, HSV is a better color space for things like this. Perhaps you can disregard the S and V channels and only do the 1D histogram for V. Try is out.

The bin with the highest count is going to be your "average" skin color.